# Call function that throws and attempt to cast the returned value, abort silently if either fails

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, throw

I'm `guard`ing the call to a method that may throw (a CoreData fetch request), and at the same time I'm casting the returned value to a specific type of array:

```
guard let results = try? managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [MyManagedObjectClass] else {

    // Bail out if fetch or cast fails:
    return
}
```

The way I understand it is that, because I'm using `guard/try?/else` (instead of `do/try/catch`), the `else` block (i.e. `return` statement) above will be executed if either of the following occurs:

1. The fetch request fails (and `throw`s)
2. The fetch request succeeds but casting of the returned value to `[MyManagedObjectClass]` fails.

The code above works, but the after control successfully passes the `guard` check,  the variable `results` ends up as being of type `[MyManagedObjectClass]?` ("***optional** array of `MyManagedObjectClass`*").

So if I want to -say- loop through the array elements **I have to first unwrap it:**

```
if let results = results {
    // now, 'results' is of type:
    // "(non-optional) Array of MyManagedObjectClass" 

    for element in results {
        // (process each element...)
    }
}
```

I **could** use `as!` instead of `as?` when casting after the `guard` statement; that makes `results` a non-optional array.

But then, if the fetch succeeds but the cast fails, It will still trigger a runtime error (crash) instead of control flowing to the `else` block, right?.

**Is there a smarter way?** (catch both errors, end up with a non-optional array)

---

**Note:** I understand that lumping both failure causes (fetch and cast) together into one `else` block is not the best design, and perhaps I should check for both separately (perhaps I should use the more traditional `do/try/catch`), but I would like to better grasp the details of this complex construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `try` call into parentheses:

```
let results = (try? managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as? [MyManagedObjectClass]
```

otherwise `try?` will apply to the whole expression, generating an optional value that gets assigned to `results`.

Comment: Great, this is the kind of insight I was looking for. Thanks!